# Unable to return multiple results from a function in order to print them within a sub

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to return multiple results from a function in order to print them within `GetInfo()` sub. When I make the function return one item and print that within `GetInfo()`, It works flawlessly but in case of returning multiple results I get stuck, as in ***`getHTTP = elemText, elemlink`*** and then `oText, oLink = getHTTP(Url)`.

I've tried:

```
Function getHTTP(ByVal link$) As String
    Dim oHttp As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object

    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Set post = Html.querySelector(".summary .question-hyperlink")
        elemText = post.innerText

        'The following line is commented for now. I would like to print it as well within the sub 
        'elemlink = post.getAttribute("href")

        getHTTP = elemText
    End With
End Function

Sub GetInfo()
    Const Url$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim oText$

    oText = getHTTP(Url)
    Debug.Print oText
End Sub
```

> ***How can I print the `link` and the `title` of a post within `GetInfo()` which should be processed by `getHTTP()` function keeping the existing design intact?***

Comment: If you can't change the parameters of getHTTP, save the value to global variables.

Comment: I can change the parameter of `getHTTP()`, if it is needed.

Comment: If you are using this for multiple calls then consider passing oHttp  as part of function signature rather than creating  a new each time. Even better instantiate in a class and hold there.

Comment: Yeah, I got your point @QHarr. The thing is the existing sub is producing mutiple results already using http requests. The function is helping here to add few fields to the current results. Moreover, the link being passed to the function is different from the one being used within sub. It's basically some sublinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Function getHTTP(ByVal link$) 
    Dim oHttp As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object

    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Set post = Html.querySelector(".summary .question-hyperlink")
        elemText = post.innerText
        elemlink = post.getAttribute("href")

        getHTTP = Array(elemText, elemlink)
    End With
End Function

Sub GetInfo()
    Const Url$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim results

    results = getHTTP(Url)
    Debug.Print results(0), results (1)
End Sub
```

Probably better to create a simple Type or Class and return that though.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new type in a new class module named `HttpData`.

For each property, you should create a getter and setter function.
Here is the sample of `HttpData` class module with 2 properties:

```
Option Explicit

Private mVar1 As String
Private mVar2 As String

Public Property Let Var1(ByVal strValue As String)
    mVar1 = strValue
End Property
Public Property Get Var1() As String
    Var1 = mVar1
End Property

Public Property Let Var2(ByVal strValue As String)
    mVar2 = strValue
End Property
Public Property Get Var2() As String
    Var2 = mVar2
End Property
```

Note: make sure you add some meaningful names instead of Var1, Var2.

Change the signature of your function:

```
Function getHTTP(ByVal link$) as HttpData
```

In the function, add the declare and populate the returning object:

```
Function getHTTP(ByVal link$) As HttpData
   Dim result As New HttpData

  .. some code that gets the data
  With result
    .Var1 = "1"
    .Var2 = "some more"
End With

Set getHTTP = result
End Function
```

Usage:

```
  Set oHttpData = getHTTP(Url)
  Debug.Print oHttpData.Var1
  Debug.Print oHttpData.Var2
```

Comment: I've rectified the script complying with your suggestion This is how [the complete script](https://pastebin.com/Ups7z5qg) looks like. However, when I run the script, it throws [this error](https://filebin.net/pcbp8zpgu3luyzz0) pointing at this line `oHttpData = getHTTP(Url)` within sub @EylM.